# formula field condition

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, formula, formula-field, if

I want to express this condition with my new formula type field that returns text

> Green Flag: is still valid
>
> Orange Flag: 1 year approaching its end.
>
> Red Flag: no longer valid so exceeds the "End date"

Example :

```
Start date: 01/01/2022
End date: 31/12/2024
  if the date 01/01/2022 my fields will be Green Flag ,
If the date 31/12/2023 my fields will be Orange Flag
If the date 31/12/2024 my field is Red Flag
```

==> My formula :

```
IF( OR( Start_Date__c = TODAY(),IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagGreen.png")) , 
OR( Start_Date__c  < TODAY() > End_Date__c),IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagOrange.png" )),
OR(  End_Date__c  = TODAY(),IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagRed.png" )
))
```

I am not sure if the condition is correct or not .

Comment: In your `OR()` statements, you are checking: whether a date field has a certain value to an image insertion. I don't think that is what you are intending to do. From Salesforce [help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm): `OR` "Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns TRUE if any expression is true. Returns FALSE if all expressions are false."

Comment: @Moonpie , should I Use just IF() ? any suggestion from you ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you write your formula more like code it is usually much easier to follow.  (You may have it that way on your end and it just copied/pasted into your question differently.)  Something like this:

```
IF( 
  OR( 
    Start_Date__c = TODAY(),
    IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagGreen.png")
  ), 
  OR( 
    Start_Date__c  < TODAY() > End_Date__c),
    IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagOrange.png" )
  ),
  OR(  
    End_Date__c  = TODAY(),
    IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagRed.png" )
  )
)
```

---

Secondly, here is the documentation for Salesforce Formula Operators and Functions: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/customize_functions.htm

---

`OR(logical1, logical2...)`: Checks whether any of the arguments are true and returns TRUE or FALSE. Returns FALSE only if all arguments are false

`IMAGE`: Inserts an image

`IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`: Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns a given value if true and another value if false.

---

Your `OR` statements are checking whether either a certain date comparison is TRUE *OR* an image insertion is TRUE.

What you want is to test that date comparison, and then insert an image if that comparison is true; otherwise, make another comparison.  For this you can use nested `IF` statements (like can be seen in an example in the linked Salesforce documentation).

In your first `IF`:

- `logical_test`: date comparison
- `value_if_true`: image to insert
- `value_if_false`: next check - which will be another `IF` statement
- etc.

*UPDATE: As @DerekF pointed out in a comment, your comparison of `Start_Date__c  < TODAY() > End_Date__c)` is invalid. That could be changed to `AND(Start_Date__c  > TODAY(), End_Date__c < TODAY())`.*

Taking your code (plus the *UPDATE* change) would give this:

```
IF(
  Start_Date__c = TODAY(),
  IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagGreen.png"),
  IF(
    AND(
      Start_Date__c  > TODAY(),
      End_Date__c < TODAY()
    ),
    IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagOrange.png" ),
    IF(
      End_Date__c  = TODAY(),
      IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/Icons/FlagRed.png" ),
      // YOU NEED SOME VALUE HERE IF THIS IS FALSE
    )
  )
)
```

But note that if `Start_Date__c` is prior to (earlier than) today, OR if `End_Date__c` has passed, then whatever you put in `// YOU NEED SOME VALUE HERE IF THIS IS FALSE` will be used. If you want it to be a red flag in those cases, you can leave out the last `IF` and just use the red flag image.

Comment: The `Start_Date__c  < TODAY() > End_Date__c` that you used from the OPs question (the second IF) isn't valid.  There's probably a way to extract `$Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c` too. Maybe it's possible to finagle `CASE` into working.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I should have looked more closely.  I was more worried with/focused on the `IF`/`OR` logic issues.

Comment: Edited for the invalid date check. I'll let the OP do that `CASE` finagling, if so desired, as "homework". :)